# $C_0(\Omega)$ is not dense in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis

---

### Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open set. Show that $C_0(\Omega)$ is not dense in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

### Notation :$f \in C(\Omega)$ and f has compact support then $f \in C_0(\Omega)$.

My attempt: Assume that $C_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Lets seek a contradiction. By the assumption for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist a function $g \in C_0(\Omega)$ such that $|f-g|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$. So we have $\mu(x \in \Omega: |f-g| > \varepsilon) = 0$. I tried to find an open subset of $\{x \in \Omega: |f-g| > \varepsilon\}$, but i failed. Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: Think about constant nonzero functions.

Comment: Make the question better.  Include the defintion of $C_0(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the constant function $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ for every $x \in \Omega$. Its belongs to $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Then for every $g \in \mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)$, there exists on open subset $\omega \subset \Omega$ such that for every $y \in \omega$, one has $g(y)=0$ (because $g$ has a compact support), so
$$||g-f||_{\infty} \geq 1$$

Therefore there doesn't exist any sequence $(g_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of functions of $\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} ||g_n-f||_{\infty} =0$$

i.e. $f$ cannot be written as the limit of a sequence of elements of $\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: The $\|\,\|_\infty$ norm in this case doesn't see single points.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the precision, is it better now ?

Comment: Yes it is!$\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be any discontinuous bounded measurable function on $\Omega$. (For example, the characteristic function of an open disk inside $U$). If there is  sequence $(f_n) \subseteq C_0(\Omega)$ converging to $f$ in $L^{\infty}$ then $\|f_n-f_m\| \to 0$ which implies that $f_n$'s converge uniformly to $f$. But uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

[$L^{\infty}$ norm of a continuous function is same as its supremum norm].

Comment: So this proves even more: $C_b$ (the space of bounded continuous functions) is not dense in $L^\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar I was not sure about the definition of $C_0(\Omega)$ so I wanted to look at all continuous functions instead of those with compact support or those that tend to $0$ as you approach the boundary. .